# how to get font used by special application in my pc

Tags: fonts

how to get font name  used by special application in my pc

i have a exe and i will change font of it 
i have windows 7 
no way exist for example in spy++

is a Persian text and ...  character is specially for Persian not in Arabic 
but in tahoma font for example its supported

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1270742740091001200.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1270742740091001200.png)

Comment: Please be more detailed and descriptive about your situation. Start with the platform you're on. Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: Are you looking to go in with a hex editor and change it in the exe?

Comment: Do you mean the arabic (I think it's arabic, if not, sorry) or the latin text?

Comment: yes is a Persian text and ...  character is specially for persian not in arabic 
but in tahoma font for example its supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find out what font is being used you can take a screenshot and use a site like [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to figure out the font being used.

If you want to then alter the .exe to change the font being used, that's a whole different (and much harder) problem.

Comment: There is always the option of finding out what font it's using, then overwriting that system font file with the one you want it to use and leaving the EXE alone :)

Comment: I tried this website after posting an image from Windows Explorer.  It recommended a bunch of fonts costing from $40-$100, despite the fact that I'm sure the font is probably Calibri or something, a font included with windows...